# What kind of model & controller should I use in ASP MVC 3, if I want a dynamic dropdown from db?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model, drop-down-menu, controller

I've been looking for hours the solution.

I've 3 models atm.

Priority:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IssueReportManagementTest.Models
{
    public class Priority
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Category:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IssueReportManagementTest.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the problem is that I've a Issue model and I want dynamic dropdowns from the other models.

Issue

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace IssueReportManagementTest.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        [Key]
        public int IssueID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Added { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modiefied { get; set; }


        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Priorities { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Is this correct? And what do I need in the Controller if I want to get dropdowns from priorities and categories. And yes they're stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have taken from my scenario, you can modify and adapt it to fit in with your code.

On my view I have a dropdown that displays the different banks.

My action method where I set the dropdown's values from the database:

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
{
     MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
     {
          Banks = bankRepository.GetAll()
     }

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

This is what my view model looks like (just a partial view):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public int BankId { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Bank class:

```
public class Bank
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

This is my dropdown's code in the view:

```
<td>Bank:</td>
<td>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(
          x => x.BankId,
          new SelectList(Model.Banks, "Id", "Name", Model.BankId),
          "-- Select --"
     )
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BankId)
</td>
```

I hope this helps.  It doesn't do anything fancy, it just populates a dropdown.  Shout if you need more clarification.

Comment: public ActionResult MyActionMethod() where is this method located? controller, model or somewhere else?

Comment: That method goes into your controller.  You need to name this method to what you need it to be.  Something like Create, Edit, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your Issue class you have Navigation Properties for Priority & Category but you also need Foreign Keys for each (use int)

Then you can bind the DDl selected item to these Foreign keys via a SelectList &  DropDownListFor.

If you need a code example let know and ill post something up.

**EDIT**

Add theFK's to your Issue class

```
 public class Issue
 {
    [Key]
    public int IssueID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Added { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modiefied { get; set; }

    public int PriorityID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
```

I use the ViewBag to populate DDL's like this :

```
    ViewBag.Genre = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "GenreName", Model.GenreId);
```

The Model (Issue) is what you pass to the View and I use ViewBag to poulate DDL's as its not part of your model, you are only interested in setting CategoryID in the model

And then in your view :

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenreId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GenreId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Genre, new { @class = "ddl" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GenreId)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: so should I put it like this?

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

Comment: Look at the example that I have given.

Comment: Yes but I dont think you need to tell EF that its a [Foreign Key] (although it might be good practice) I use simple Props in my EF POCO's. see my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xN7pI-cLJvM&context=C4c84c5cADvjVQa1PpcFOk-cxHCg8RwXa58TLdASOHTjnRobG6ZwE=) tutorial (Pretty good one) there is example of drop-down menu of Prefix.db